# GDrive. Moving files from shared folder to shared folder using google-api-javascript-client

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I've developed feature to manage gdrive files using gapi. I've used following function for moving files:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.update({
          fileId: id,
          addParents: parentId,
          resource: null,
          removeParents: parents,
});
```

Moving files from folder to folder works fine, but issue appears when I was trying to move files from shared folder to shared folder. Two folders was shared to me by another user. Files moving was happening with a delay, not immediatelly (few minutes). As I could see in network tab, file object property `parents` changed with a delay. I repeate, moving files from my own folders works well. Have someone faced the same problem?